# PHP, call-time pass-by-reference error

Tags: php, web, configuration, error-handling, warnings

PHP has a list of possible errors and warnings:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.constants.php

I wonder which constant (in the list above) to be disabled in error reporting in order to run my old PHP codes which contain a lot of call-time pass-by-reference.

Inside php.ini there's a config option to allow call-time pass-by-reference but that config option is no longer applicable in new PHP release (present, oct 2013).

I've tested passing-by-reference purposely, and got this error:
**Fatal error: Call-time pass-by-reference has been removed in D:\septeni\tests\pass-by-ref.php on line 7**

But this is fatal error, I can't disable this because I won't be able to see other errors. Or the solution is only getting the old version of PHP to run my web application on?

Comment: If your code generates an error, the error will say what level it is (notice, warning, whatever). All you have to do is run your code, then set error reporting accordingly.

Comment: good solution, i'm trying :)